# Difference between binary and character datatype in MySQL? with examples and limitation

Tags: mysql

What is the difference between binary and character datatype in MySQL? need examples and limitation info

Comment: Then start by looking at the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

The BINARY and VARBINARY types are similar to CHAR and VARCHAR, except that they contain binary strings rather than nonbinary strings. That is, they contain byte strings rather than character strings. This means that they have no character set, and sorting and comparison are based on the numeric values of the bytes in the values.  for more details

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-data-types.htm

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/binary-varbinary.html

and also read

[MySQL "binary" vs "char character set binary"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15334607/mysql-binary-vs-char-character-set-binary)