# Laravel Schema Builder : Creating a binary(16) column

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5.5

Using Laravel 5.5 and Mysql (10.1.19-MariaDB)

For a  md5 hash I want a binary(16) column.
Let's call the colum **url_hash**

When using :

```
$table->binary('url_hash');
```

it will give me a BLOB column.

source : https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#creating-columns

I have seen all kind of hacks or plugins around the web for this , but what is the most simple one without any external plugins that could break on the next update?

Cheers

Comment: Are you using MySQL?

Comment: yes, will update .. thanks for noticing.

Comment: you could do it with DB::statement('CREATE TABLE t (url_hash BINARY(16))');

Comment: @SariYono : Will that not create a double table?   aka an error?  But thanks , I think it is getting me on the right track.

Comment: you can use alter table if you prefer in a separate call ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laravel author [recommends](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1606) to do a `DB:statement` call and run the raw SQL.

If you are running migration, you could run this raw SQL after `Schema::create`:

```
DB::statement('ALTER TABLE table_name ADD url_hash binary(16) AFTER some_column');
```

Depends on use case, you could need to run this raw SQL to drop the column before dropping the table:

```
DB::statement('ALTER TABLE table_name DROP url_hash');
```

Answer (score 17):

You can just set the *character set* to *binary*.

```
$table->char('url_hash', 16)->charset('binary');
```

This is actually shown as a real *binary* column type with a length of 16 in MySQL Workbench.

There shouldn't be any difference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15335682/5412658

Comment: Whoever lands here, I can confirm, it really creates correct binary column in MySQL.

`$table->char('url_hash', 16)->charset('binary');`

Results:

`CREATE TABLE test (url_hash binary(16) NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;`

Answer (score 10):

Extend the `MySqlGrammar` class, e.g. in `app/MySqlGrammar.php`:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Support\Fluent;

class MySqlGrammar extends \Illuminate\Database\Schema\Grammars\MySqlGrammar {

    protected function typeRealBinary(Fluent $column) {
        return "binary({$column->length})";
    }

}
```

Then use a macro to add your own column type:

```
DB::connection()->setSchemaGrammar(new \App\MySqlGrammar());

Blueprint::macro('realBinary', function($column, $length) {
    return $this->addColumn('realBinary', $column, compact('length'));
});

Schema::create('table', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->realBinary('url_hash', 16);
});
```

Comment: Would you still say the same today?